# How do i set the text of a TextView to a value of an integer from another class

Tags: java, android

How do i set the text of a TextView to a value of an integer from another class.

the main activity where i want the text set below

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);


   TextView counterText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);


   counterText.setText();


}
```

the class below

```
public class Ship implements Serializable {

        private static int counter = 0;
        public int getCounter()
        {
            return counter;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.valueOf` to show Integer in TextView,as:

```
counterText.setText(String.valueOf(new Ship().getCounter()));
```

Answer (score 3):

For a starter this should help

```
Ship s=new Ship();
int i=s.getCounter();
String value=String.valueOf(i);
counterText.setText(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you cannot access the UI component of 2nd activity while being in first activity. So the best way is to pass the value through `putExtra` method of intents and then set it to *textview* in the *onCreate* of 2nd activity by getting it. Here is link which shows this method: http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-using-intents-to-pass-data-and-return-results-between-activities/